# When to use plural verb or not

Tags: verbs

The best part of me is my hands. or The best part of me are my hands.

Comment: The verb should agree with the subject of the sentence. 'part' is singular and therefore you use the singular verb form, 'is'. If you want to be obsessively correct then you should say, "The best parts of me are my hands" but that is overdoing things in my opinion.

Comment: We were debating that. So thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Singular - "The best part of me **is** my hands".

The reason is not because of the hands being multiple but because you are referring to a single part.

Comment: I don't think this answer really explains it.  What about: "My hands are the best part of me" ? There is still a single part but the verb is plural..

Comment: True, but then there's "What **is** the best part of me?" which would be singular. The problem we have here is the question "What **is** the best part of me?" (singular) being answered with "My hands **are**." (plural)

Comment: As an addition, is it possibly because the concept of **best part** which is singular has come first?

Comment: It was intended as a rhetorical question :-) I explained my reasoning in a comment. I can't now give an actual answer as the question is marked as duplicate.